# Speed Up MySQL (MyISAM) COUNTs with WHERE Clauses

Tags: php, mysql, count, myisam

We are implementing a system that analyses books. The system is written in PHP, and for each book loops through the words and analyses each of them, setting certain flags (that translate to database fields) from various regular expressions and other tests.

This results in a `matches` table, similar to the example below:

```
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field                  | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                     | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| regex                  | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| description            | varchar(250) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| phonic_description     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_high_frequency      | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| is_readable            | tinyint(1)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| book_id                | bigint(20)   | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| matched_regex          | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| [...]                  |              |      |     |         |                |
+------------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Most of the omitted fields are `tinyint`, either 0 or 1. There are currently 25 fields in the matches table.

There are ~2,000,000 rows in the matches table, the output of analyzing ~500 books.

Currently, there is a "reports" area of the site which queries the `matches` table like this:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM matches
WHERE is_readable = 1
AND other_flag = 0
AND another_flag = 1
```

However, at present it takes over a minute to fetch the main index report as each query takes about 0.7 seconds. I am caching this at a query level, but it still takes too long for the initial page load.

As I am not very experienced in how to manage datasets such as this, can anyone advise me of a better way to store or query this data? Are there any optimisations I can use with MySQL to improve the performance of these `COUNT`s, or am I better off using another database or data structure?

We are currently using MySQL with MyISAM tables and a VPS for this, so switching to a new database system altogether isn't out of the question.

Comment: What is the output of `EXPLAIN SELECT [the rest of your query]`?

Comment: @jcmeloni http://dpaste.com/690316/

Comment: Super; it provides confirmation for precisely the solutions that @Marek and others have described.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add multi index to this table as you are selecting by more than one field. Below index should help a lot. Those type of indexes are very good for `boolean` / `int` columns. For indexes with `varchar` values read more here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html

```
ALTER TABLE `matches` ADD INDEX ( `is_readable`, `other_flag`, `another_flag` )
```

One more thing is to check your queries by using EXPLAIN {YOUR WHOLE SQL STATEMENT} to check which index is used by DB. So in this example you should run query:

```
EXPLAIN ALTER TABLE `matches` ADD INDEX ( `is_readable`, `other_flag`, `another_flag` )
```

More info on EXPLAIN: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html

Comment: @AlanEdwardes, to optimize it even more, which ever column will expect the smallest result set should be listed first...  Ex: if the IS_READABLE flag = 1 would return 50,000 entries and you OTHER_FLAG = 0 would only return 8,000 records, I would put the OTHER_FLAG in the first position of the index.  Likewise, consider your "ANOTHER_FLAG" column.

Comment: Thanks for that, I had no idea the order in indexes was important. It seems indexing is the way to go though.

Comment: @AlanEdwardes, you cannot use the `EXPLAIN` with an ALTER statement [https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/using-explain.html).
See the first point :
`Permitted explainable statements for EXPLAIN are SELECT, DELETE, INSERT, REPLACE, and UPDATE`

Answer (score 5):

You need to use indexes, create them on the columns you do a `WHERE` on most frequently.

```
ALTER TABLE `matches` ADD INDEX ( `is_readable` )
```

etc..

You can also create indexes based on multiple columns, if your doing the same type of query over and over its useful. phpMyAdmin has the index option on the structure page of the table at the bottom.

Comment: Yup. A compound (i.e multi column) index on `(is_readable,other_flag`another_flag)` should improve time for query above a lot. The problem is in potentially large amount of indexes needed.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is the number of different queries needed (so lots of indexes), but it's the accessing of data that needs to be fast, not INSERTing so much. Is there an unreasonable number of indexes to have? Would having, say 25 on the single table above impact write speed much?

Comment: Speed mainly depends on amount of data in the table. INSERT/UPDATE will be slower (depends on amount of data in the table) as the indexes need to be rebuild. I would not advice to create many indexes. The good approach is to create few multi-indexes for the same columns (in different order) and than use EXPLAIN to check which index is used by DB. After knowing this remove not used indexes and leave only one. You may want to repeat it later when the number of data in table increases as this may change and other index may be more optimal.It really depends on the specific usage and data in table.